# Are arbitrary nesting depth with sequelize associations with self reference possible?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like to have recursive nesting on a self referencing association, 3 or 4 levels deep if possible. Is it possible?

This works:

`ContentItem.childrenAssoc = ContentItem.belongsToMany(ContentItem, {
  through: ContentItemChildren,
  foreignKey: 'ParentId',
  as: 'Children',
});
ContentItem.addScope('detail', {
  include: [
    {
      model: models.ContentItem,
      as: 'Children',
    },
  ],
});`

But below fails with:
    `/Users/mkm/clients/frn/sites/frn-platform-meta/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:198
    self._expandAttributes(options);
    TypeError: self._expandAttributes is not a function`

`ContentItem.childrenAssoc = ContentItem.belongsToMany(ContentItem, {
  through: ContentItemChildren,
  foreignKey: 'ParentId',
  as: 'Children',
});
ContentItem.grandChildrenAssoc = ContentItem.belongsToMany(ContentItem, {
  through: ContentItemChildren,
  foreignKey: 'ParentId',
  as: 'GrandChild',
});
ContentItem.addScope('detail', {
  include: [
    {
      model: models.ContentItem,
      as: 'Children',
      include: [{model: models.ContentItem.grandChildrenAssoc, as: 'GrandChild'}],
    },
  ],
});`

Appreciate any advice. Thanks, Mike